# Error al crear store procedure en MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Estoy creando un procedimiento almacenado en Mysql

01  CREATE PROCEDURE prcGrabarLocationGPS(
02   _latitude DECIMAL(10,7),
03  _longitude DECIMAL(10,7),
04  _speed INT(10),
05  _direction INT(10),
06  _distance DECIMAL(10,1),
07  _date TIMESTAMP,
08  _locationMethod VARCHAR(50),
09  _userName VARCHAR(50),
10  _phoneNumber VARCHAR(50),
11  _sessionID VARCHAR(50),
12  _accuracy INT(10),
13  _extraInfo VARCHAR(255),
14  _eventType VARCHAR(50),
15  _imei VARCHAR(255),
16  _numero VARCHAR(255)
17  )
18  BEGIN
19     INSERT INTO gpslocations (latitude, longitude, speed, direction, distance, gpsTime, locationMethod, userName, phoneNumber,  sessionID, accuracy, extraInfo, eventType, imei, numero)
20    VALUES (_latitude, _longitude, _speed, _direction, _distance, _date, _locationMethod, _userName, _phoneNumber, _sessionID, _accuracy, _extraInfo, _eventType, _imei, _numero);
21    SELECT NOW();
22  END

pero me indica un error

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 20

No logro ver que es lo que esta incorrecto.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerde usar el comando `DELIMITER`, ver [Delimiters](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/delimiters/):

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE prcGrabarLocationGPS (...)
BEGIN
...
END//

DELIMITER ;
```